# Windows Phone 7: Animation transitioning between pages?

Tags: silverlight, animation, windows-phone-7, transitioncontentcontrol

I'm trying to figure out how to transition between pages. I've looked at a few blog posts. I downloaded a sample project from [this blog](http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/16/Bring_Back_Page_Transitions_to_the_Windows_Phone_List_Application_Template). I pasted the `mainFrameStyle` into my App.xaml's `ResourceDictionary`. I added the following to the `Application` tag:

```
xmlns:layout="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
```

It complains about the `TransitioningContentControl`tags:

```
The tag 'TransitioningContentControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit'.
```

What am I doing wrong? The blog post is from a few months back; perhaps something has changed now that I'm on the final version of the SDK?

That post also said that the wp7 SDK is based on SL 3, which surprised me. I thought it was SL 4?

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the Silverlight toolkit? silverlight.codeplex.com/.

1. Download and install the toolkit.
2. Add a reference in your project to
   System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit.dll (for example after installation, it was found in: Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Bin\System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolk it.dll)

BEWARE: I have to say that this control isn't ready for prime time yet though.  It seems to be a little buggy, and will crash if you navigate while a previous transition is running.  For example if you go to a page and quickly navigate backwards.

some more implementation details that I wrote about a while back: http://cdn.microsoftplatformready.com/assets/PortingIPhoneToWindowsPhone7.pdf

Comment: I do have Silverlight downloaded, but I can't find that reference in VS. Is it supported on the phone?

Comment: this is the "silverlight toolkit", not "silverlight".  the toolkit is a seperate project: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034

Answer (score 0):

The location of the Nov 2010 release is inside the windows phone folder and not silverlight folder.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Toolkit\Nov10\Bin